# requests.get not returning webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

When trying to return the below site I get the following error:

"The requested object does not exist on this server. The link you followed is either outdated, inaccurate, or the server has been instructed not to let you have it."

Any help would be great, tried parsing with urllib as well, no luck. Pasting the link into the browser seems to work fine.

```
r = requests.get('https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: You should try *pasting that link again* in your browser, because it doesn't work. You'll get the same `404 Not Found` message.

Comment: Worked for me..

Comment: Well, then maybe the site has some anti-scraping protection in place.

Comment: It does a redirect for me to `https://us.spdrs.com/en/etf/spdr-msci-canada-strategicfactors-etf-QCAN`. If it doesn't work in Python but does in a browser, there might be some anti-scraping measures. Look up how to forge headers, specifically the user agent, as a first pass at evasion. That said, I did it with requests and it worked for me (once, were you hammering it?).

Comment: Yes, link works fine for me, I was not hammering it put did hit it a 5-6 times in a few mins. I'll try under a different IP thanks for the feedback guys

Answer (score 1):

As suspected by @CuriousGeorge, results vary depending on source IP:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN')
for r in response.history:
    print(r.status_code, r.url)
print(response.url)
```

US:

```
301 https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://us.spdrs.com/en/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://us.spdrs.com/en/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://us.spdrs.com/etf/spdr-msci-canada-strategicfactors-etf-QCAN
https://us.spdrs.com/en/etf/spdr-msci-canada-strategicfactors-etf-QCAN
```

France:

```
301 https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
302 https://fr.spdrs.com/fr/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://fr.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
302 https://fr.spdrs.com/fr/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
301 https://fr.spdrs.com/product/index.seam?cid=0
https://fr.spdrs.com/fr/product/index.seam?cid=0
```

Canada:

```
301 https://us.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
https://global.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=QCAN
```